# Is a divorce buy-out of a house a taxable event?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gain, virginia

To be clear, this is a question about US Federal Taxes, and I live in Virginia, which is an equitable property (not community property) state.  Additionally, I understand this is not a legal forum wherein I can get legal advice.  I just want the general idea, so that *when I go to my lawyer and/or accountant*, I have an idea of what to expect.

So, my soon-to-be ex-wife and I have an exceedingly expensive house with a lot of equity in it.  As part of the divorce settlement, I am going to be bought out of my share of the equity.  The question is, is this payout taxable income, or just a redistribution of my portfolio?  I'm assuming that in many ways, the buyout would be treated as if I were selling the house, but the happiest answer I could receive is, "No - it's not."

So, what's the deal then - is a buyout a sale subject to capital gains, or is it just a reshuffling of assets?

Comment: Just a side note, but the *one-time* capital gains exclusion hasn't existed since [1997](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/over-55-home-sale-exemption.asp). In its place, homeowners can [exclude capital gains multiple times](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc701.html) in their life if they meet certain eligibility requirements.

Comment: Will the answer depend on whether you live in a community property state or not? In any case, please consider revealing the state of which you are a resident, and possibly the state in which the house is located in, if that is different.

Comment: Good question, not legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transfer of property between spouses, or between ex-spouses incident to divorce, is not generally a taxable event.

The controlling section is [IRC §1041](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1041).  If the divorce agreement includes cash for transfer of the house, then it's not likely to be taxable.  This rule would not apply, however, if your ex-wife is a nonresident alien (and thus the property would skip tax when it left the US tax-free).

Answer (score 2):

> So, what's the deal then - is a buyout a sale subject to capital
>   gains, or is it just a reshuffling of assets?

It is subject to capital gains, of course. There's no "in-kind" exchange for personal residence.

What there is, however, is [primary residence exclusion](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p523/ar02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000200709).

If you transfer the property to your wife before the divorce, the answer might be different, but having it non-taxable to you will make it taxable for her, and I'm not sure she'd like it.

Community property rules, if apply, may change your basis - making the profit higher or lower than you think.

I'm sure the accountant helping you with the divorce can give you a formal opinion on this, I'm not a professional.

Comment: It's not taxable.  §1041 excludes it from income if it's between spouses or incident to divorce.  If it's in the divorce settlement, then the transfers of values are tax free - as if made between spouses.